# ASP.NET linq Select with multiple joins

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I've this database from EF code first, and now i have a difficult time getting my data.

I have the following **entities**:

**Program** : is a workout program that contains Workouts.

**Workout** : is a day routine that contains a list of Sets.

**Set**     : is an Exercises repeated x times with y load.

**Exercise**: is an gym exercise which contains a Region.

**Region**  : is a region on the human body and contains Muscles.

**Muscle**  : is a muscle on the human body.

## Model examples

Here are 3 model examples

```
    public class Workout
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}
 public class Set
{
    [Key]
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    //Foreign key for Exercise
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ExerciseId")]
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public decimal Load { get; set; }
    public decimal Order { get; set; }
}

    public class Exercise
{
    [Key]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //Foreign key for Region
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

And the scaffolded controller

```
// GET: api/Workouts
    public IQueryable<Workout> GetWorkouts()
    {          
        return db.Workouts;
    }
```

So that only gives me a Workout object with its iCollection Sets is null.

```
// GET: api/Workouts
    public IQueryable<Workout> GetWorkouts()
    {          
        return db.Workouts.Include(w => w.Sets);
    }
```

By including Sets i can get the corresponding Sets.

But what if i would like to get a Workout, including the Sets, and those Sets would include Exercises, and those Exercises would include Regions which in the end had a list of Muscles?

And what if i want a workout from id, like this:

```
        [ResponseType(typeof(Workout))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetWorkout(int id)
    {
        Workout workout = db.Workouts.Find(id);
        if (workout == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(workout);
    }
```

How will i then include **Sets**?

**EDIT**
And from the Visual Studio Template /Help page, i can see the following:

```
GET api/Workouts/{id}
```

Should provide med with:

```
{
   "workoutId": 1,
   "name": "sample string 2",
   "description": "sample string 3",
   "sets": [
   {
     "setId": 1,
     "exercise": {
     "exerciseId": 1,
     "name": "sample string 2",
     "description": "sample string 3",
     "regionId": 4,
     "region": {
     "regionId": 1,
     "regionName": "sample string 2",
     "muscles": [
        {
          "muscleId": 1,
          "latinName": "sample string 2",
          "dkName": "sample string 3",
          "enName": "sample string 4",
          "description": "sample string 5"
        },
        {
          "muscleId": 1,
          "latinName": "sample string 2",
          "dkName": "sample string 3",
          "enName": "sample string 4",
          "description": "sample string 5"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

But it just wont happen, im open for anything that returns me a full Program in JSON. skype, teamwievr, stack, another solution, anyhting.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eagerLevels)?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `SetId` in `WorkOut` ?

Comment: user1429080 i havent seen exactly that, but i've searched the internet try, and stackoverflow is my last resort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And finally i got it:

```
 public class Exercise
 {
     [Key]
     public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     //Foreign key for Region
     //public int RegionId { get; set; }
     public virtual Region Region { get; set; }    //had to be virtual -.-
 }
```

Comment: Hey, glad you got it working. Couldn't get back to you earlier, lost electricity and all connections for 2 days because of a snowstrom.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the models set up correctly, chaining the `Include()` methods should work.

```
public IQueryable<Workout> GetWorkouts()
{          
    return db.Workouts.Include(w => w.Sets.AsQueryable().Include(s => s.Excercises.AsQueryable().Include(e => e.Regions.AsQueryable().Include(r => r.Muscles))));
}
```

Comment: no, in the code (s => s.Exercise) the s is a Workout, not a Set, because the Sets is a collection, but each set has 1 Exercise. so i have to throw a foreach in there or?

Comment: Could you make a short example of the collection you expect the query to return? I misunderstood the structure a bit..

Comment: I get this error with your code (from workouts up till and including Exercise)

{"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.\r\nParameternavn: path"}